# How to monitor for all the registry values change under a key?

Tags: wmi

I want to monitor the registry values changed under a particular key like

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\File History\`

I know we can achieve this using `RegistryValueChangeEvent`, but I need to watch for changes that happen on any registry value under a key, without specifying any `ValueName`.

Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RegistryTreeChangeEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class for monitor  the changes to a key and its subkeys.